# Fixing values/numbers to 2decimal places

Tags: php, html

[image]

I have column named Profit/Loss(USD) , this column contains numbers which are defined by a set of calculations and the variable for this column. The problem is that some values come out like 7.0E-6 . How do i adjust all to 2 decimal places? all answers appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the in built function [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) like so:

```
number_format($number, 2);
```

If you don't want to add thousand seperators, you can simply skip it:

```
number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
//                              ^ No thousand seperator
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the function number_format to format your number

```
$formatted_number = number_format($number, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `printf` family of functions, for example:

```
echo '<td>'.sprintf('%.2f', $number).'</td>';
```

The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) lists all the formatting codes you can use.